# jQuery not working on my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery is not working on my HTML page. Probably some code/syntax issues. Need a look from some good pair of eyes.

```
<head>
<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#insert").click(function(){
      alert("ok");
  });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="submit" id="insert" value="Insert"/>
</body>
</html>
```

My file is there I am sure, but my alert is not popped up. Please help

Comment: Where is the `body` tag?

Comment: Is jquery file is loading

Comment: @undefined: The `body` tag can be implied in HTML5. [Yes, really.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) *(I'm not saying I think it's a good idea...)*

Comment: I would like to advice you to call Jquery hosted on Google. It will be fast and secure as well as you won't encounter such conditions in future.
Example: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know that, apart from that browsers are very kind, most of them create the body tag even when the doctype is HTML4/XHTML. I think it's not a good a idea too.

Comment: @undefined: Yeah, this is one of the several areas where HTML5 was mostly codifying what browsers already do... :-)

Comment: @akshayb: *"...as you won't encounter such conditions in future..."* The problem had nothing whatsoever to do with the location of the script file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) is *not* self closing tag, you need to remove forward slash at the end of `script` start tag.

*Change*

```
<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"/>
```

*To*

```
<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this `<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"/>`

to this : `<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

self closing script tag's will not work - you need this -

```
<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```